Unreal Engine 4.23.1 WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc error
I coded the game with UN 4.23.1. This version provides to export HTML5 project. There is a problem with a texture (red house).
While there is no problem on the desktop computer, the house disappears on laptops and mobile devices and gives a texture error.
No House
When click up icon there is a house
Texture Info
Matrix Info
